# Taking images from text with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have some HTML code with text and images inside (I don't know how long is this text and how many images it has). Is there any way to take all images and put them into 1 div element using AngularJS?

Code which I have:

```
<p>aaaaaaaaa<img>aaaaaaa<img>a<img>aaaa...</p>
```

Code which I want:

```
<p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p><div><img><img><img></div>
```

is there any way of doing this?

Comment: What is source of the html and how is it being inserted?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without Angular, I think. What you could to is turn your piece of HTML into a jQuery object, like so:

```
var $jqueryObject = $("<your HTML code");
```

Then from this jQuery object you can extract all images, and save them in a variable:

```
var allImages = $jqueryObject.children("img");
```

Finally you can iterate over all these `img` elements and do something with them:

```
$.each(allImages, function(index, image) {
    // Do your magic
}
```

Comment: But is some way to do that in pure Angular? without JQuery?

Comment: You could use `angular.element` to wrap a piece of HTML code, instead of using jQuery's "dollar encapsulation" `$(<your HTML code>)`.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to use the library for a simple DOM manipulation, try this:

```
var p = d.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
var div = d.createElement('div');
while(img = p.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]) {
    div.appendChild(img);
}
p.parentNode.insertBefore(div, p.nextSibling);
```

Keep in mind I aimed it at the code provided so maybe throw an `ID` on the `P` and make sure you call this once the document has loaded.

Tested on Chrome, FireFox, and IE.

Comment: More efficient to do this before inserting in dom due to angular digest cycles